# Mercurial: list changeset that contain a specific file

Tags: mercurial

I have a mercurial repository that has over 300 change sets.

How can I list all change sets that contain a specific file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: Right click on the file and select revision history.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line:

```
hg log <filename>
```